# several domain controller logon

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, redundancy

I've got two domain controllers. The master is DC01 and slave Fil01. I got that problem, that some computers logon over the slave dc and not the master. How can I set the order or prevent them on logon over the slave dc?

Comment: Are you sure this is a "problem"? Because technically it is not.

Comment: `The master is DC01 and slave Fil01` - No they aren't. Domain Controllers are equivalent (other than the FSMO role holders). Users should be logging on to the domain via either DC under normal circumstances and you shouldn't be trying to influence that process. Why do you think this is a thing you should do or want to do?